# How to setup facebook app for localhost?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authentication, facebook-app-settings

Today, I've been trying to setup facebook app for localhost and I couldn't find the right solution for it. It was working in the past and I don't know what facebook updated with it...

Here's what I did:

1. I've created test app from one of my public app
2. In settings, I set site domain as "localhost" and site url as "http://localhost:8888/"
3. In settings/advanced, I set Valid OAuth redirect URIs as "http://localhost:8888/" again.

And when I try to login, I got the error message like below:

{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191
   }
}

Also I have public ip for my localhost and I tried to set it instead of localhost like "http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8888/" but it's still not working.

I'm really embarrased because it was working before. Can someone please help me out with this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you setup the field "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" in the advanced setting..since its a redirect call your browser calls it..so localhost should not be a problem..

Comment: Is that redirect_uri the -full- uri? Not any index/home/login urls that you use?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps that worked for me getting my local app working with Facebook:

**Part I:**

- goto developers.facebook.com
- Hover over the "MyApp" drop-down to the right and click "Add an app" or click [Create an APP] if that is the only option you see.
- Click "Settings" to the top left
- copy 'App Id' and 'Secret Id' to FACEBOOK_APP_ID and FACEBOOK_SECRET_ID in your .env file
- enter the app domain (eg: localhost or yourappname.app, etc.)
- click [+ Add Platform] button on the bottom of the screen and then choose "Website". Enter http://localhost:8000
- click [Save Changes]

**Part II:**

- click [+Add Product] to the bottom left
- choose Facebook Login
- Click on "Settings" underneath "Facebook Login"
- Enter your callback URL under Valid OAuth redirect URIs (eg: http://localhost:8000/login/facebook/callback)
- Turn on OAuth login for your desired allowed device types
- Click [Save Changes]

**Part III:**

- click "App Review" near the top left of the screen
- switch the "Make [your app name] public?" slider to "Yes"